# Mysql count selected query

Tags: mysql, select, count, inner-join

Please look at the tables bellow. Lets say the first one is `table1` and `table2` the other one.
I really dont know what to do about this, can anyone help me how to count like the tables below with mysql queries?

it's count how much 'red' with type 'a'

[image: its count how much red with a type]

thanks

Comment: Have you made any attempt at this? Please include your query if you have

Comment: Are you familiar with `GROUP BY`? It might be worth reading up on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `LEFT JOIN` rather `INNER JOIN` since there is a possibility that `color` does not exist on the other table.

```
SELECT  a.id,
        a.colour,
        SUM(type = 'a') TypeA,
        SUM(type = 'b') TypeB
FROM    tableColors a
        LEFT JOIN tableName b
            ON a.ncolour = b.colour
GROUP   BY a.id, a.colour
```

`SUM(type = 'a')` is a mysql specific syntax that calculates the total value on the result from boolean arithmetic. If you want to it more RDBMS friendly, use `CASE`

```
SELECT  a.id,
        a.colour,
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TypeA,
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TypeB
FROM    tableColors a
        LEFT JOIN tableName b
            ON a.ncolour = b.colour
GROUP   BY a.id, a.colour
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.colour ncolor,
  SUM(a.type = 'a') amount_a,
  SUM(a.type = 'b') amount_b
  FROM table_name a
  LEFT JOIN table_name b
     ON a.colour = b.colour
  GROUP BY a.id, a.colour
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like select count(red) from table1; I'm not sure about the syntax, you could check in here

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/counting-rows.html

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/

Answer (score 0):

From your screen, I'd say the query you're looking for is a simple `SELECT [...], COUNT(a), COUNT(b) FROM table1 GROUP BY colour`.

More precisely:

```
SELECT colour AS ncolour
  , COUNT(a) as amount_a
  , COUNT(b) as amount_b
FROM table1
GROUP BY colour ;
```

See [Mysql Counting Rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html)

P.S. I assumed that what was requested was the MySQL query to obtain table2 from table1.